# Simple MIPS question, about load byte

Tags: assembly, mips

I have the following question here

```
.data
a: .asciiz "2021"
x: .byte 7,2,12
.text
main: addi $t2, $0, 1
lb $t3, a($t2)
```

Can someone explain to me, HOW the value of $t3 is 48?

thanks
EDIT this is an another question which is similiar, and is confusing.

```
.data
a: .word 12,-5,4,0
x: .byte 5
.text
main: addi $t1, $0, 8
lw $t2, a($0)
lw $t3, a($t1)
```

How will you load word, from index 8, when 'a' has a length of 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when you add `$0` and `1`, you get `1`, which is put into `$t2`.

Then, when you evaluate `a($t2)`, that's the second byte (offset 1 since it's based at offset 0) of `a` which is the "0", ASCII code `0x30` or `48`.

---

From various pieces of information:

```
ADDI -- Add immediate (with overflow)
Description:
    Adds a register and a sign-extended immediate value
    and stores the result in a register
Operation:
    $t = $s + imm; advance_pc (4);
Syntax:
    addi $t, $s, imm

LB -- Load byte
Description:
    A byte is loaded into a register from the specified address.
Operation:
    $t = MEM[$s + offset]; advance_pc (4);
Syntax:
    lb $t, offset($s)
```

> Register `$0` always contains the hardwired value 0. MIPS has established a set of conventions as to how registers should be used. These suggestions are guidelines, which are not enforced by the hardware. However a program that violates them will not work properly with other software.

Those little snippets should hopefully be enough to explain what it's doing.

---

And, regarding your edit, you're incorrectly thinking that `.word 12,-5,4,0` has a length of 4 bytes. In fact it has a length of 16 bytes since words in MIPS are 32 bits (four bytes) wide.

So when you load from *byte* offset 8, you will get the *word* `4`.

Comment: thanks, but how did you know it was 0x30? is this common knowledge or is there a formula for figuring out the hex?

Comment: It's pretty much common knowledge, you just need to get yourself an ASCII table from somewhere (book, internet, ...). The numbers `0..9` are ASCII codes `0x30..0x39`.

Comment: Oh okay, I guess our prof will give us a ASCII sheet. If you can answer 1 more question which is similiar, which i added above.

Answer (score 0):

FYI there is an ASCII chart on page 11 of handout 4 ;) 
But I dont get this:
"when, when you evaluate a($t2), that's the second byte (offset 1 since it's based at offset 0) of a which is the "0""
The binary representation of '2021' I believe is:
00110010001100000011001000110001
So, when you say "which is the "0"" do you mean the 2nd bit from the right? Is that the 0 you are talking about?
I dont get where the zero comes from.